# Pass Multiple Strings in Python API Call

Tags: python, arrays, list, api, parameters

I am currently new in Python and working on processing some API calls. I have a set of distinct arrays that I need to pass in a parameter.

Currently, I have this:

```
requests.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?seed={7D3375FE},{A87F7113}')
```

However, this only returns the result set for the first parameter (7D3375FE). I am looking for both results to show up.

I have 11 distinct profiles I need to parse, so any help on how I can pass multiple arguments would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: That is unrelated to python or any language for that matter. The question is: does the API support that, and if so what is the format it expects?

Comment: @luk2302 - The thing is, it is hard to phrase a question when you are unsure of the process in the first place. I am using Python to try and call and whilst I saw initial result with 1 value - I figured normally you could do arrays. I myself am brand new to APIs hence I posted the question.

Comment: *"I figured normally you could do arrays"* - **no**. If you have a method `def addNumbers(a,b):` you cannot pass three numbers in just because you think it should work or would make sense, that is not how anything works. You can only do what the other side implemented.

Comment: @luk2302 I agree with you - but how can you know/understand what the other side implemented when you are new to a subject/do not know. I appreciate your technical prowess however, I have found my solution.

Comment: Look at the documentation, ask other people who used the api, look at other code using the api - if all that fails there is no other way than to try it out and if it does not work then it does no work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this does not work because that API is not built to handle that type of request. When you set `seed={7D3375FE},{A87F7113}`, it actually seems to use the string `{7D3375FE},{A87F7113}` as your seed.

If you need to run this on a number of inputs, you probably need to make multiple requests. However, if you do not care about passing in multiple seeds and simply want 11 users, you can make requests to `https://randomuser.me/api/?results=11`.